# What is wrong with my responsive html code

Tags: html, css

link: http://www.kelvinhanssen.nl/projecten/marktmix_responsive/html/bedrijven_responsive.html

I made my first responsive webpage, and it doesn't act the way I want.
When I test it in this app: http://www.studiopress.com/responsive/
My website does what it's supposed to do.
But when you display it on your phone it look like it's been zoomed out
I can't attach any images because my reputation isn't high enough.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">` to your header.

This will make it so that the phone does not 'exaggerate' its actual width when rendering the page, which is how they typically get web pages to look decent.

Comment: Thanks I spend hours trying to solve that problem! Well done, I am really happy!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I was doing my first website, it makes it look like its a desktop webpage, even though you have it set to look on a mobile webpage.

Just add this to your head part of your website, and it should work.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

Let me know if it works.